# ¿Cómo ordenar un array en PHP?

Tags: php

Necesito ordenar un arreglo  por los keys, el arreglo se va formando de acuerdo a una consulta SQL:

```
Array  (
            [Color] => YELLOW
            [Variedad] => CHERRY
            [Finca] => FINCA1
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [quantity] => 91570
            [quantity_origin] => 2096
        )
```

Dependiendo de la consulta pueden haber mas datos Ejemplo:

```
Array  (
            [Color] => YELLOW
            [Variedad] => CHERRY
            [Grado] =>  NORMAL
            [Finca] => FINCA1
            [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
            [year] => 2016
            [week] => 26
            [quantity] => 91570
            [quantity_origin] => 2096
        )
```

En este último caso agregue el valor "Grado",

En mi caso en particular yo quiero que el arreglo esté de la siguiente manera:

```
Array  (
                [Finca] => FINCA1
                [Producto] => ALSTROEMERIA
                [Variedad] => CHERRY
                [Color] => YELLOW
                [Grado] =>  NORMAL
                [year] => 2016
                [week] => 26
                [quantity] => 91570
                [quantity_origin] => 2096
            )
```

Quisiera saber si es posible hacer eso? Gracias

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que pretendes hacer es una ordenación de un array por su clave. Además es una ordenación personalizada, puesto que no existe un patrón (por ejemplo ordenar de mayor a menor o alfabéticamente), por tanto debes definir una función de comparación.

La función adecuada en php para esto es [uksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php), que ordena un array por su clave (key) y permite pasarle como parámetro la función de comparación. El código sería algo así:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {                 // Esquema básico de función de comparación
    $orden = array (                   // Definir un array con el orden
        "Finca" => 1, "Producto" => 2, 
        "Variedad" => 3, "Color" => 4, 
        "Grado" => 5, "year" => 6, 
        "week" => 7, "quantity" => 8, 
        "quantity_origin" => 9);

    return (($orden[$a])) < (($orden[$b])) ? -1 : 1;            // Comparador
}

uksort($array, "cmp");                 // LLamada a la función de ordenación
```

Comment: Gracias por tu explicación, muy bueno pero no me funcionó, hice tal cual como lo sugeriste, investigué sobre la función pero en mi caso no funciona!

Comment: De nada, que raro... [Test en PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/266b7514b9a7dd3df80d048f17f00b1d35057bc2) funciona.

Comment: Con este método, en la función de comparación debe aparecer cualquier campo posible, cada uno con su orden. Puede que en mi respuesta no estén todos. 
[Test en PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42512a4a1ff219ae81218a5f69c466d8a7b00014)

Comment: Vale voy a revisar muy bien la función, quizás es  mi que no funciona

Comment: Mi error fue en la pregunta, lo que pasa es que mi array es multidimensional, por eso no me funciona

Comment: Ya lo intenté y es que como el array es multidimensional la función no me da, ya intenté cambiando el código pero no me funcionó, pero me gustó mucho tu respuesta!