# Ordenar array php kb, mb, gb

Tags: php, array, ordenamiento

Tengo un array que lleno de una consulta. Lo que obtengo es lo siguiente:

```
array (size=9)
  '128 GB' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '156' (length=3)
  '16 GB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '106' (length=3)
      1 => string '331' (length=3)
  '32 GB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '293' (length=3)
      1 => string '549' (length=3)
  '32 MB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '29' (length=2)
      1 => string '419' (length=3)
  '4 GB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '42' (length=2)
      1 => string '376' (length=3)
  '512 MB' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '230' (length=3)
  '64 GB' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '118' (length=3)
  '8 GB' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
      1 => string '315' (length=3)
  '90 KB' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string '431' (length=3)
```

Después lo imprimo en un HTML en unos `input checkbox`:

```
<?php foreach ($memories as $name => $ram ): ?>
  <li value="<?= implode(',', $ram) ?>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_<?= $name ?>"/>
<label for="id_<?=  $name ?>" class="css-label radGroup2">
 <?= $name ?>
</label>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Todo funciona bien, el único inconveniente es que quiero ordenar para que no me salga *128gb*, *16gb*, *32gb*... Quiero poder ordenar eso por el valor, en lugar de ordenar alfabéticamente, que me ordene por tamaño.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo ordenar un array en PHP?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16679/c%c3%b3mo-ordenar-un-array-en-php)

Comment: No es un duplicado de esa pregunta. Cierto que se pide ordenar un array, pero es un caso muy especial en el que hay que ordenar por key realizando operaciones con la key en particular, algo que (si no me equivoco)  PHP no ofrece y habría que crear un código específico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que inventar la rueda una y otra vez? :)

En la notas aportado por los usuarios de [php.net - filesize()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.filesize.php#usernotes), hay dos funciones muy bonitos:

La primera función es [filesize2bytes()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php#92418), convierte el tamaño del archivo, legible por humanos, en bytes.

Ejemplo: `'10 MB' => 10000000`

```
function filesize2bytes($str) { 

    $bytes = 0; 

    $bytes_array = array( 
        'B' => 1, 
        'KB' => 1024, 
        'MB' => 1024 * 1024, 
        'GB' => 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 
        'TB' => 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 
        'PB' => 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, 
    ); 

    $bytes = floatval($str); 

    if (preg_match('#([KMGTP]?B)$#si', $str, $matches) && !empty($bytes_array[$matches[1]])) { 
        $bytes *= $bytes_array[$matches[1]]; 
    } 

    $bytes = intval(round($bytes, 2)); 

    return $bytes; 
}
```

La segunda función es [human_filesize()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filesize.php#106569), convierte bytes en tamaño del archivo, legible por humanos.

Ejemplo: `10000000 => '10 MB'`

```
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 0) {

  $sz = 'BKMGTP';
  $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);

  return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) .' '. @$sz[$factor].'B';
}
```

Ahora solo se necesita combinar las dos funciones y *et voilà!*

```
$sortMemory = [];
$newMemory  = [];

foreach($memory as $bytes => $value) {

    // guardamos todo en el mismo orden pero con bytes
    $sortMemory[filesize2bytes($bytes)] = $value;
}

// ordenamos el array por la clave
ksort($sortMemory);

foreach($sortMemory as $readable_size => $value) {

    // y guardamos el array ordenado pero con el tamaño del archivo legible
    $newMemory[human_filesize($readable_size)] = $value;
}
```

Y ya con tú código, (poquito modificado), tienes tu lista ordenado:

```
<?php

foreach ($newMemory as $name => $ram ):

    // crea una id_90_KB sin espacio !
    $name_ID = 'id_'.str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
?>

<li value="<?php echo implode(',', $ram) ?>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="<?php echo $name_ID; ?>"/>
  <label for="<?php echo  $name_ID; ?>" class="css-label radGroup2"><?php echo $name; ?></label>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Resultado:**

```
<li value="431">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_90_KB"/>
  <label for="id_90_KB" class="css-label radGroup2">90 KB</label>
</li>    

<li value="29,419">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_32_MB"/>
  <label for="id_32_MB" class="css-label radGroup2">32 MB</label>
</li>    

<li value="230">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_512_MB"/>
  <label for="id_512_MB" class="css-label radGroup2">512 MB</label>
</li>    

<li value="42,376">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_4_GB"/>
  <label for="id_4_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">4 GB</label>
</li>    

<li value="8,315">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_8_GB"/>
  <label for="id_8_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">8 GB</label>
</li>    

<li value="106,331">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_16_GB"/>
  <label for="id_16_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">16 GB</label>
</li>    

<li value="293,549">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_32_GB"/>
  <label for="id_32_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">32 GB</label>
</li>    

<li value="118">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_64_GB"/>
  <label for="id_64_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">64 GB</label>
</li>    

<li value="156">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_128_GB"/>
  <label for="id_128_GB" class="css-label radGroup2">128 GB</label>
</li>
```

**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e081cad3c50e864a69ff0dbc3567ee7fd841d58a)**

Comment: Muchas gracias... Tambien me funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Aunque PHP ofrece diferentes funciones para ordenar usando llaves (`ksort`, `krsort` y `uksort`, puedes ver la lista completa en la [documentación oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/array.sorting.php)), ninguna de ellas ofrece exactamente lo que buscas porque no te permite especificar tu propia función de comparación, y las que podrían funcionarte usan el valor y en algunos casos se pierde la llave (*key*).

Me temo que te va a tocar hacer algo específico para tu caso. Una alternativa sería crear una array con las llaves, ordenar ese array (con alguno de los métodos nativos de PHP, como `usort`) y modificar un poco el código después.

Aquí te dejo una opción, lo que hace es que transforma el valor a bytes y entonces realiza la comparación de manera numérica):

```
<?php

$memories = array(
    '128 GB' => array('156'),
    '16 GB' => array('106', '331'),
    '32 GB' => array('293','549'),
    '32 MB' => array('29', '419'),
    '4 GB' => array('42','376'),
    '512 MB' => array('230'),
    '64 GB' => array('118'),
    '8 GB' => array('8','315'),
    '90 KB' => array('431')
);

// creamos un array auxiliar que tendrá dos valores: la llave y el valor original
$memories2 = array();
foreach($memories as $name => $value) {
    $memories2[] = array($name, $value);
}

// función de comparación
function comparaSizes($a, $b) {

    // separamos el valor de la llave en arrays (0 => número; 1 => unidad)
    $arrA = explode(" ", $a[0]);
    $arrB = explode(" ", $b[0]);

    // calculamos el valor en Bytes para cada unidad
    switch ($arrA[1]) {
        case "GB": $arrA[0] = intval($arrA[0]) * 1000000000; break;
        case "MB": $arrA[0] = intval($arrA[0]) * 1000000; break;
        case "KB": $arrA[0] = intval($arrA[0]) * 1000; break;
        default: $arrA[0] = intval($arrA[0]);
    }

    // calculamos el valor en Bytes para cada unidad
    switch ($arrB[1]) {
        case "GB": $arrB[0] = intval($arrB[0]) * 1000000000; break;
        case "MB": $arrB[0] = intval($arrB[0]) * 1000000; break;
        case "KB": $arrB[0] = intval($arrB[0]) * 1000; break;
        default: $arrB[0] = intval($arrB[0]);
    }

    // devolvemos la comparación de los valores en Bytes
    return ($arrA[0] < $arrB[0]) ? -1 : 1;
}

// ordenas el array auxiliar usando la función de comparación que acabas de crear
usort($memories2, "comparaSizes");

// tu mismo código adaptándolo un poco
foreach ($memories2 as $name => $ram ): ?>
  <li value="<?= implode(',', $ram[1]) ?>">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxG5" id="id_<?= $ram[0] ?>"/>
<label for="id_<?=  $ram[0] ?>" class="css-label radGroup2">
 <?= $ram[0] ?>
</label>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Cuanod ejecuto ese código, el resultado queda algo como esto:

```
[ ] 90 KB
[ ] 32 MB
[ ] 512 MB
[ ] 4 GB
[ ] 8 GB
[ ] 16 GB
[ ] 32 GB
[ ] 64 GB
[ ] 128 GB
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, probando algunas soluciones y comparando la documentación me queda claro como utilizar en este caso las Keys del array para utilizar una u otra función. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto, deberia de funcionar, ya que recree el array de la misma manera

```
$memories=array(
    "32 GB"=>["293","456"],
    "128 GB"=>["500","600"],
    "4 GB"=>["800","700"]
);
var_dump($memories);
uksort($memories,'strnatcasecmp');
var_dump($memories);
```

El resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La cosa está en que el array también puede tener KB y MB, no solo GB.

Comment: Solución ingeniosa, pero no funciona si hay diferentes unidades. Quizás se pueda cambiar de alguna manera "sencilla" para solucionar eso.

Comment: Ummm Eso si es un problema xD

Comment: Gracias, este ejemplo es claro cuando se trata únicamente de una nomenclatura... por así decirlo.

Answer (score 0):

Sería mejor si pudises pasar la consulta sql que utilizas y ver si desde allí puedes obtener los datos en orden usando ORDER BY.

Por ejemplo, puedes colocar ORDER BY ram ASC

Ram como ejemplo, lo sustituyes por el nombre del campo de donde obtienes esos valores (128gb, etc).

Esa debe ser la solución más eficaz ya que con sólo unas letras lograrías tu objetivo, sin tener que añadir más pues entre más comlpejo lo vayas creando, más difícil de mantener.

Comentas qué tal!